# RpgSQL - Why is it so slow?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I try to access my PostgreSQL-database from R using [RpgSQL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RpgSQL/index.html).

My database is very big and the queries are quite sophisticated. Therefore I understand that I have to wait a bit.

However, if I use [pgAdmin III](http://www.pgadmin.org/) as a client, a query takes maybe 5 seconds. When I use RpgSQL the same query literally takes ages.

I can't see the reason for that, as the server and not the client hast to do the work, right?

Can you give me a reason and possibly a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: You could give it a try using RODBC and see if that's faster. RpgSQL's version number 0.1-5 does not sound very mature yet to me.

Comment: thank you. Maybe you are right, but RODBC seems very sophisticated to install (especially as I don't have admin rights on my working-computer - sad but true)

Comment: You can create a 'User DSN' in Windows for which you don't need admin rights via 'Set up data sources (ODBC)' in the Control Panel. Ah, but you need the MySQL ODBC driver for that, and installing a driver does require admin rights... sorry! And are you actually on working Windows?

Comment: How much data are you actually bringing in? Perhaps add a `LIMIT` clause the the SQL to check that the thing actually works. It could well by that the way R is having to read/parse/decode your data into things it understands is what is taking all the time. If all else fails, **profile** your code to see where R is taking all the time.

Comment: Its because its based on RJDBC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also the [RPostgreSQL](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgreSQL) package 
which is actively maintained.  As it sits directly on top of the PostgreSQL API, it 
should be faster than going via ODBC with [RODBC](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RODBC).

Here is a quick example from a database I keep at home---it gets a thousand simple rows 
in a tenth of a second:

```
R> library(RPostgreSQL)
Loading required package: DBI
R> drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
R> con <- dbConnect(drv, password="....", dbname="beancounter")
R> system.time(res <- dbGetQuery(con,
+>             "select * from fxprices where date >= '2005-01-01' limit 1000")) 
   user  system elapsed 
  0.030   0.000   0.113
R> dim(res)
[1] 1000    8
R>
```

Comment: thank you Dirk! I read that you are a maintainer of RPostgreSQL. Actually I would love to use RPostgreSQL but it seems hard to install it on a Windows x32 machine!?