# How to install RPostgreSQL on Windows

Tags: r, postgresql, compilation

(How) is it possible to install RPostgreSQL on a Windows XP machine (running R 2.12.1) without admin-rights?

(Btw. this post is a follow-up to this post: [RpgSQL - Why is it so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803677/rpgsql-why-is-it-so-slow))

[edit]

What I tried yet:

First I tried to find a documentation on how to install RPostgreSQL on Windows. I didn't succeed (I could only find a documentation for MacOS [here](https://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/)).

After that I tried a naive solution:

```
install.packages('RPostgreSQL', type='source')
```

Didn't actually work (I can give you the error message later, at the moment R is busy).

I'm sure there are more possibilities like compiling the source by hand, but I haven't done this before with R packages, so I didn't try it yet.

Comment: Please give some details on what you tried already, did it work or not, and why: [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: For example, is postgreSQL already installed on the machine ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need [Rtools](http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/) and Postgres installed on your machine to be able to build RPostgreSQL from source, and unfortunately Windows binaries are not available.

Another option is to try [RJDBC](http://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/), see [here](http://extats.blogspot.com/2009/12/connecting-r-and-postgres-via-jdbc.html). You will only need to find the RJDBC Postgres driver jar somewhere. You don't need to install that jar, just put it in a directory somewhere and give RJDBC the right path.

Only question is how fast this solution will be, please inform us when you got it working.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, RpgSQL uses RJDBC, so using the latter will most likely not result in any speed up (unless RpgSQL introduces a bottleneck somewhere).

Comment: The RpgSQL package works on Windows, uses RJDBC and would be easier to use than RJDBC directly.  See the installation instructions link on its CRAN page: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RpgSQL/index.html  .  Note that RJDBC (hence RpgSQL) are more suitable for smaller projects.

Comment: ok, in my case it's a big project. I'm using RpgSQL already and have difficulties with it. Maybe the problem is RJDBC.

Why is there no precompiled RPostgreSQL package?

Comment: Because CRAN does not have PostgreSQL headers/libraries to compile and link RPostgreSQL against.   If you ask on the rpostgresql-list, maybe someone will share their local package with you.